# How can I check if my Java project uses Log4j and which version?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, ivy

Due to the [Log4Shell vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log4Shell) I would like to search and find out if my Java project is implementing Log4j directly or by dependencies, and which version.

I have, for example, projects with these dependency management tools:

1. [Maven](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) project
2. [Apache Ivy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Ivy) project
3. Old legacy project without any dependency management

How can I do this on these types of dependency management tools?

Details about the vulnerability (including mitigation steps):

[CVE-2021-44228](https://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2021-44228)

[Apache Log4j Security Vulnerabilities](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/security.html)

Comment: check the dependency tree for dependencies. check your code.

Comment: See a few places to check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70315727/where-to-put-formatmsgnolookups-in-log4j-xml-config-file/70315976#70315976) on top of development areas

Answer (score 6):

You may run Maven dependency tree from the command line inside your project:

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

In the output do a search for `log4j`.  If you find it, it might mean that your project is either directly including `log4j`, or another dependency is including `log4j` as a transitive dependency.

Comment: but keep in mind, having it as a dependency doesn't automatically mean you are using it.

Comment: @Stultuske Good point, but then again some tools such as SonarQube might not care, if they deem that even including the library poses a risk.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, how do we be sure about library which does not show log4j in hierarchy tree but uses it internally. For example: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging/1.1.1

Comment: @Magnum23 If `commons-logging` uses `log4j` my understanding is that it should show up in the dependency tree.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen `commons-logging` seems to have `log4j` dependency as **optional**, so I think developer has to explicitly declare it...

Answer (score 4):

If you use Maven and Linux, you can run:

```
mvn dependency:tree | grep log4j
```

This will check your dependencies and show results only if you have Log4j as a dependency.

And if it is a transitive dependency, and you want to check the dependency it came from, you can use:

```
mvn dependency: tree | grep -B20 log4j
```

It will show 20 lines before Log4j on the screen. If you still can't see the main dependency where it comes from, you can increase from 20 to 50, and so on until you find it.

```
KKKK
```

Answer (score 3):

So far I'm satisfied what [Syft](https://github.com/anchore/syft) and *[Grype](https://github.com/anchore/grype)* provide. These tools list all code dependencies of a given [Docker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Docker_%28software%29) image or a directory containing code - independent of the stack! Easy setup and quick execution.

It's Java-independent though and more generic than your specific question for a Maven-based solution. So it is up to you if it's of use or not.

Comment: These seems really interesting, not only finding the log4j but in broader use - integrated as part of a CI/CD pipeline...